# Create a flash message when validation fails in Laravel FormRequest

Tags: laravel, validation, session

I'm trying to refactor my custom flash error message after the validation rules failed in any Laravel `FormRequest` extended classes.

Previously, I used `withValidator` method as docs:
[Adding After Hooks To Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests).

**RegisterRequest.php**

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $feedback = [
            'title' => 'Failed',
            'message' =>  'The given data was invalid.',
            'type' => 'error',
            'timeout' => 5000
        ];

        // session()->flash('feedback', $feedback);

        // Or,

        // return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator)->with([ 'feedback' => $feedback ]);
    }
}
```

Then, I separated this into the trait file and used it all the extended class of FormRequest.

**Is it possible to define `withValidator` globally in `AppServiceProvider.php` or somewhere else? Then, let me know?**

Comment: I do not understand very well why are you making a Trait for this? and register globally ?. On the other hand it seem you are using withValidator but don't you need to hook with a callback like the example in Laravel doc with de after method in validator object?  Like `$validator->after(function(){ });`

Comment: @ManuelGlez I want to show both flash message and input error message at the same time on the frontend. And almost all of my `FormRequest` class are using same `withValidator` method which means same flash message. Instead of calling traits on every file, I want to set it globally.

Comment: Why  don´t you create a CustomFormRequest that extends Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest and in your CustomRequestForm add your Trait. Make all your FormRequests extends from your CustomRequest.

Comment: @ManuelGlez That's fine - but every time when the `FormRequest` class is created, I have to make changes to it, I don't want that to happen. If all happened internally, it would be nice to me. That why, I am stuck on the topic of `withValidator` globally.

Comment: You could try FormRequest::macro() or FormRequest::mixin() as is Macroable to register in AppServiceProvider with custom functionality

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution would be register this macro in your AppServiceProvider inside the boot method.

```
FormRequest::macro('customError', function (){

           $feedback = [
               'title' => 'Failed',
               'message' =>  'The given data was invalid.',
               'type' => 'error',
               'timeout' => 5000
           ];

            session()->flash('feedback', $feedback);


       });
    }
```

After that, you can use this data in your messages() method from your CustomFormRequest

```
public function messages(): array
    {

       return  [
            ...
            'error'=>$this::customError()
        ];

    }
```

What finally result in your session populated with custom error message.

Comment: Oh! A new approach got it. But my mind is still not accepting your answer. One or the other hand I have to call `$this->customError()` or extends `CustomFormRequest` or use 'traits' every time. Then, what's the difference than previous.

Comment: I think your mind do no understand what this code is doing, 

I have test this solution and it is working perfectly, you don`t have to use any trait, nor extends anything, you just call  a  Static Method  in your FormRequests when an error occur and boom your message is flashed to session.

 If you do not accept any of solutions I have offered is  al little be disheartening, sorry man, but I'm sure you can implement a better solution by yourself.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not working, it's working at all. I just said that if I have to change on it (whatever reason), then I have to go through both `AppServiceProvider` and `CustomFormRequest` , which I don't want. And the `withValidator` method is calling automatically by default, so why is it not working just by registering `FormRequest::macro('withValidator', $callback )`. By doing this, I have to take care only `AppServiceProvider.php` file. That's what I'm telling you. At last, thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Simply it is not posible to pass a validator object to your app booting method, simply because **that object do not exist** at boot time. App is booting and bootstrapping. BTW in `FormRequest::macro('withValidator', $callback )`  withValidator string is the static function you can call after implementation, and $callback is a closure which return something. I´m wating for a better solution from you ;)